# Update partial json in postgresql database using jpa query

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa, java-11

I have database table- "menu" which along with other fields, on of which is "objectlist" of type jsonb as follows
`{"item1":"abc","item2":"something"}`
I want to update partial json using jpa query in the following manner:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "update \n" + " config.menu" + " set step_therapy.objectlist \n" + " = jsonb_set(objectlist, '{item1}', '=:new_value', true) " +" where \n" + " menu.objectlist@> CAST(:old_val AS jsonb)\n" + ";")
    List<Menu> updateObj (@Param("new_value") String newVal, @Param("old_val") String oldVal);
```

But it's not working. Please help if possible what i'm doing wrong?
Expected Output:
`{"item1":"kgi","item2":"something"}`

Comment: What does it mean not working ? what happens ? any exception ?

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov  ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json
  Detail: Token "=" is invalid.

Comment: @AARTIGOEL Were you able to solve it? Could you please help with the code snippet?